# Trying to run the command 'appium-doctor' on Windows Command Prompt but getting an error

Tags: appium, appium-desktop

I installed Appium Desktop for windows and used the Command Prompt to install Appium server and appium-doctor via npm but I get the following error after typing 'appium-doctor' in the command prompt:

> 'appium-doctor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How can I get appium-doctor to run?

**Edit: I found out what was wrong. In %PATH%, I had two variable locations written down in the same line separated by a semicolon:**

> C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs

I removed the semicolon and put the two variable locations in different lines:

> C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

Everything is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you either need to specify the full path in cmd, or add the path to the executable in your os PATH environment variable

Comment: You mean adding "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm" to path because I have done that already

Comment: maybe appium-doctor is in some subfolder of npm . you have to check where apium-doctor.exe is located

Comment: added 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium-doctor' to the path but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: have you tried restarting the system? type "echo %PATH%" in CMD and see what s in there

Comment: I ran that command and realized that I had two variable locations written down in one line separated by a semicolon.